# Changing a language for a specific logged in user in php

Tags: php, internationalization

I have a blog application in codeigniter php framework and  i am wondering how to implement this concept. In my blog i have a profiles section where logged in users can fill their profile and also choose the language they want to view their blog in.

I know how to internationalize the blog but the concept where a user account is displayed in the choosen language is not clear to me.

After a user has choosen the language and i have save this in a database,how can i switch the language when a user logs in?.

Is there a function i can use in my controllers to use the choosen language for that specific logged in user only?

Edit

I have saved my locales in french.json, russian.json etc text files.

Comment: As the chosen language is a property of the user profile you save to your database you have that information available during the login process, when you fetch the profile to setup the users session. Now all you have to do is load the matching locale asset based on what language is set inside your session. You do that for _all_ users, always depending on their chosen language.

Comment: Do i load the language file in every controller?

Comment: Certainly always when there is something to localize, since you need to localization asset for that. Typically some sort of singleton or lazy load factory pattern is implemented to load such assets. I cannot directly answer to your question, since you did not say anything about your architecture or framework you use or anything. So I don't know what "load the language file" actually means in your case.

Comment: I am using sails for the backend and codeigniter for the frontend. Anyway,i found sails has something called policies that handles what i am looking for http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/internationalization/locales